# Create a query using 2 tables with 3 columns and key id

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to do a query and having a huge brain block.  Here is the situation

Table 1

```
Account     |     Sen1     |    Sen2
-------------------------------------
1234                 1             0
1235                 0             1
```

Table 2

```
ID          |      Name
--------------------------
1                  Box
```

Results trying to achieve

```
Account     |     Name
------------------------
1234              Box
1235              Box
```

Code attempted

```
SELECT Table1.account, table1.sen1, table1.sen2, 
table2.id, table2.name   
FROM table1 
OUTER JOIN table2 ON (table1.sen1=table2.id) AND (table1.sen2=table2.id)
```

Comment: How is Table1 relate to Table2?

Comment: Sorry,  trying to obtain the sql script to achieve the result

Comment: What is Sen1 and Sen2? Id of Table2?

Comment: By id  of table 2

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: SELECT Table1.account, table1.sen1, table1.sen2,table2.id,table2.name

Comment: Use OR instead of AND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But the following should do:

```
SELECT m.Account, k.Name FROM Table_1 m 
INNER JOIN Table_2 k ON k.ID = m.Sen1 OR k.ID = m.Sen2
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    table1.account,
    table2.name
FROM
    table1
JOIN
    table2 ON
    table1.sen1 = table2.id
```

Question isn't very clear but looks like you're looking for something like this?